# How can I create a virtual sound card on ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: server, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I hosted an websocket application on an ubuntu server which listens to incoming audio streams from an angular application. But the issue is that the audio stream does not reach the websocket. And the error I get is that there is no sound card available. I tried installing alsa-utils with `sudo apt install alsa-utils` but still can get the audio stream. When I do `modprobe snd-aloop` it tells me module snd-aloop does not exist. Please can someone help me with this. Thanks